# Sleep deprivation doesn't worsen polysomnography measures but lowers O2 saturation

Tags: sleep-apnea

Using an [oximetry ring](https://www.lookeetech.com/products/lookee-ring-sleep-monitor-w-vibrating-notification-for-sleep-apnea), I found that my O2 saturation and score was much better when I wasn't sleep deprived.  I looked online to see if sleep deprivation worsened sleep apnea, and found evidence [here](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/emres/longhourstraining/sleepdeprivation.html) and [here](https://academic.oup.com/sleep/article/26/8/1038/2707907).

The second source is much more scientific, but I'm confused by the passage "Acute sleep deprivation did not worsen most OSA parameters as measured by polysomnography. A lower minimum oxygen saturation in mild OSA subjects after sleep deprivation".  Polysomnography measures O2 as well, so the first sentence seems contradict the second one.

To understand this, I noted that the study use "Rechtschaffen and Kales criteria" to score the sleep.  I was hoping to find a description of the scoring [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1388245709005471?via%3Dihub), but it just contains snippets of the source.

Can anyone please explain the contradiction?

I am not a life scientist, so the difference may be obvious.